# Views Taxonomy Select Brothers Terms

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm working with Drupal 7.

I have a view with a page display that takes a taxonomy term from the url as an argument.

mywebsite.com/my-view-page/xxx
where xxx is the taxonomy term.

Now I would like to put in this page a block where are listed the taxonomy terms that have the same parent of xxx.

For example, if this is my taxonomy:

aaa
- yyy
- xxx
- zzz
bbb

In the xxx page I would like a block containing;
yyy
xxx
zzz

Is there a way to do it?
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add a 'block' display to your view and just create a contextual filter for it.  Under the 'Contextual Filters' section of the view, select that you're going to provide a 'Taxonomy term: Parent term'.

Then, when you're setting it up, specify that if the filter isn't present, you want to 'Provide default value' and select the option of 'Taxonomy Term ID from URL', or, alternatively, select 'Raw value from URL' and set it to pick up the second path component (so select '2'), since that's where it seems you'll be specifying the term (I hope it's the term id though, since that's what it'll be looking for.  If not, go with my first suggestion!!!!).

Does that work?